# Вопрос по PHP, что обозначает эта запись?

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, что обозначает эта запись?

```
for($i=1;$i<=11;$i++){
                    if($battlepart['casualties_attacker'][$i] <= 0) { ${dead.$i} = 0; }elseif($battlepart['casualties_attacker'][$i] > $data['t'.$i]){
                        ${dead.$i}=$data['t'.$i];
                    }else { ${dead.$i} = $battlepart['casualties_attacker'][$i]; }
}
```

Интересует именно вот эта часть - `${dead.$i}`. Никогда ранее такой записи не встречал..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто. В php можно написать ${'var1'} и это будет переменной. dead.$i, как я понимаю, это конкатенация какой-то константы с числовой переменной - строка. Объединяем оба факта и получаем генерацию и / или инициализацию переменных, отличающихся номером в имени.